# php readfile() сохраняется ли файл на сервер?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, сохраняется ли файл в tmp, или просто на сервер если отдавать файл способом указанным ниже, и сильно ли он нагружает сервер, если будет большое количество запросов?

```
<?php
    $file = 'http://site.com/folder/application.exe';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Как вы поняли ссылка на файл находится на удаленном сервере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл не сохраняется на вашем сервере, а читается в буфер объемом 8Кб и сразу отдается пользователю (если буферизация вывода не включена).

Но скрипт ждет пока весь файл будет прочитан и отдан пользователю.

Источники: [phpclub](http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-readfile.11732/#post-106029), [habr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/151795/)

Comment: Если это работает на связке nginx + php-fpm, то файл попадёт в промежутке во временный файл в папке, указанной директивой [`fastcgi_temp_path`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_temp_path) конфига nginx. Стоит рассмотреть вариант отдачи файла самим веб-сервером, не вовлекая php.

Comment: @Sergiks, не знал этого.