# Проиграть музыку из VK.com со своего сервера

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Получаю url аудио с помощью api vk.com.
Url привязан к ip, с которого сделан запрос, т.е. сам сервер получает файл, а при обращении с другого адреса отдается 404.
Необходимо сделать проигрывание трека для каждого посетителя сайта.
Есть сервисы типа ПростоПлеер, позволяющие проиграть любому но такое решение не подходит; можно скачать файл себе, а потом проиграть его пользователю, решение не подходит. Т.е. нужно как-то сразу ретрансировать аудио из вк пользователю, чтоб сервер выступал как прокси.
В какую сторону копать? Какие функции нужны? Какие заголовки?

Comment: nginx заставьте как прокси работать у себя на сервере.

Comment: Ума не приложу, как это сделать. Подскажете, как-то реализовать исключительно на php можно?

Comment: Про nginx и проксирование вы можете найти в гугле. По php вот вопрос был аналогичный http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448388/php-readfile-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80 (тоже обратите внимание на комментарий к ответу).

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему так:

1. создал файл `player.php`, принимающий get-параметр с идентификатором аудио;
2. поместил туда код:

   ```
   $len = get_headers($file,1);
   if ($len[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
       header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
       header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
       header('Content-Length: ' . $len['Content-Length']);
       echo file_get_contents($file);
       exit;
   }
   ```

   , где `$file` -  ссылка на аудио, которую мы получаем по api или парсингом
3. в аудиоплеере в качестве источника указываем ссылку на `player.php` c get-параметром.